# Adding items in set (Python)

Tags: python, set

I just start learning about adding items in set (Python), but then I don't understand why this happens

```
thisset = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}

thisset.update("durian", "mango", "orange")

print(thisset)
```

and I get the output like this:

```
{'i', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'cherry', 'n', 'u', 'a', 'apple', 'banana', 'd', 'e', 'g'}
```

What I want is put the other 3 items into the set, what else I need to add/change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the reference, `set.update(*others)` will update the set, adding elements from all others, what it does is `set |= other | ...`. So in your case, what `thisset.update("durian", "mango", "orange")` does is `thisset |= set("marian") | set("mango") | set("orange")`. To accomplish what you want, you need to pass a list or a set, say `thisset.update(["durian", "mango", "orange"])` or `thisset.update({"durian", "mango", "orange"})`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put curly braces inside `update`:

```
>>> thisset = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
>>> thisset.update({"durian", "mango", "orange"})
>>> thisset
{'orange', 'banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'cherry', 'durian'}
>>>
```